# How to load the dynamic data on scrolling in Express Js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Right now,the dynamic data from Mongo db is getting loaded all at once but we want to load it through scrolling.As we scroll the data should get loaded in one single page.

// What we have tried is-Added Lazy loading carousel but isn't working.

```
function loadStartUp(){         
    $.ajax({
        url: '/createSection',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var i = 0;
             data.forEach(function(model){
                 console.log(model)

                $('#tbody').append(`
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="tagModalWindow">${model.name}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="tagModalWindow">${model.description}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="tagModalWindow">${model.dashtype}</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `)

                navItem(model.name,i); 
                createSection(model.name, model.frequency, i,model.type,model.entity, model,model._id);
                if(model.parameters.length > 0){
                gettingData(model.parameters[0].para, model.parameters[0].startPeriod, i, model.parameters[0].calendar, model.parameters[0].month, model.parameters[0].calc, model.parameters[0].chartType, model.parameters[0].type, model.parameters[0].period, model.parameters[0].indi, model.parameters[0].k);  
                }
                i++;
            });

            carousel();
        }
    });


    function carousel(){
        console.log("carousel");
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items: 2,
            singleItem: false,
            lazyLoad: true,
            loop:true,
            //Basic Speeds
            slideSpeed: 200,
            paginationSpeed: 800,
            rewindSpeed: 1000,
            autoWidth:true,
            responsiveClass:false,
            //Autoplay
            autoPlay: false,
            stopOnHover: false,
            // Navigation
            navigation: false,
            navigationText: [
                "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white left'></i>",
                "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white right'></i>"
            ],
            rewindNav: false,
            scrollPerPage: false,
            //Pagination
            pagination: false,
            paginationNumbers: false,
            responsive: true,
            responsiveRefreshRate: 200
        });
    }
```

This is where we fetch data from db:

```
app.get('/createSection', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next)=>{         
    var query = {user:req.user._id};
    dashModel.find(query,(err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } 
        console.log(data)

        res.send(data)
      })
    });
```

I am new to Express.Js.How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case, you need to add `pagination` from both sides

Comment: [Pagination in MongoDB](https://www.codementor.io/arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr)

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination. For client side I recommend to use the following pattern if SEO matters, as this is the only way google is able to crawl your paginated data:
https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-create-an-seo-friendly-infinite-scrolling-page/

and for back-end side I recommend to use mongoose for database handling and I just picked a random library for pagination for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate